# Correct way to filter M:N relations on parameter stored in relational table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
class User
  has_many :payments
  has_many :course_runs, :through => :payments
  ...
end

class Payment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course_run

  aasm do
    state :new, initial: true
    state :paid
    state :canceled
    state :refunded
    ...
  end
...
end

class CourseRun
  has_many :payments
  has_many :users, through: :payments
  ...
end
```

User has N CourseRuns, CourseRun has M Users. Relation is stored in Payments table. Payment has states. The question is: what is the correct Railsway of loading paid CourseRuns for user? I would do something like

`user.payments.where(aasm_state == paid).course_runs`

but I don't think thats the correct way, this is point where scopes could be useful somehow (not sure tho how to reference entities across each other in lambda queries) and second thing is this returns Array[CourseRun], but I want ActiveRelation, as I want to continue on filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You already have has_many through. You can add scope to Payment as follows:

```
scope :confirmed, -> { where(aasm_state: 'paid') }
```

And than you can use merge method (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) as follows

```
u = User.first 
paid_course_runs = u.course_runs.merge(Payment.confirmed)
```